# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, datepicker, angular15

I am implementing an application using Angular 15. I use Angular Material there. I need to add a date picker and after inserting the code snippet below I'm getting an error.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="freshness" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Error:

```
Error: src/app/dialog/dialog.component.html:18:51 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

18       <input formControlName="freshness" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
```

If you need further information to solve my issue please put a comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modules should be imported into your component if it's a [standalone component](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) (otherwise, in your module imports):

- [MatDatepickerModule](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) from '@angular/material/datepicker'.
- [MatNativeDateModule](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) from '@angular/material/core'.

Besides, make sure you also import the `MatInputModule` and `MatFormFieldModule` to make them work.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have imported both `MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule` together. Then I imported them independently.Now error is solved. Angular versions after 10, these 2 should be imported independently.